# Framing Oops? Advice?

Tags: doors, framing

So, in this DIY basement finishing project of mine, I've learned more than I ever thought I could know but I've been able to correct many simple mistakes so far. Here's my latest, I have basically just finished up with the framing for my basement following 99% of the builders plans that were left when they built this home two years ago. Here is my latest dilemma: the plans call for a 28" door into the bathroom. I was going over all of my work, and noticed for whatever reason, I framed that rough opening for a 32" door. Meaning the rough opening right now is 34". I suppose I could install a 30" door and would be able to cover up the 2", but if I want to install the original 28" door, what's the best way to go about closing in these additional 4"? Sorry if there is rambling on this post, but I've heard good things about this site so I figured I'd look for advice here. Thank you!

Comment: Why not just leave it alone and install a 32 inch door and be done with it.

Comment: Wider is better with doors. Doubly with bathroom doors. Triply if you should ever find yourself "mobility impaired."  Use the 32"

Comment: If you find an answer helpful please upvote or accept the green check mark this will help others to find answers.

Answer (score 1):

As the frame is still "rough" (whatever you mean precisely), I will assume that the basic framing is there but not the finishing wood.

So, add another 2" stud on each side then finish with the wood and extend the wall surface as necessary. Use a strong glue and screws so they never move.

Comment: Thanks Mike. Yeah, it's literally just the framed walls up. That was my original plan but I wasn't sure if that would be okay with those studs not being fastened to the concrete floor.

Comment: Hopefully the studs you already have are secured thoroughly.

Comment: They are, it's a rock solid shorter wall. I just wasn't sure per general building "code" if there was anything wrong with that.

Comment: A 28" door is pretty small. I would go with the 32" door or even change that to a 36" door.

Comment: @d.george both my bathroom doors are 27.5" and are fine for me and both my sons - and we are all 6foot plus and I am the "wrong" side of 100kg. If there is a wheelchair about then that may mean a wider door, but a friend of mine who is in a wheelchair gets through the 27.5" doors fine.

Comment: Just don’t finish the rough opening two tight or you may not be able to get a pre-hung door in or have trouble squaring up a door.

Comment: @EGrant23 you don't need the shimmed studs to be on the bottom plate like the rest of the wall. Instead just continue the infilled stud to near the floor so you have nailing and support for the drywall and trim. Side note, you're in your basement, I assume that you're working on concrete. Be sure that all your bottom plates in contact with the concrete are pressure treated

Comment: Thank you! All the bottom plates are indeed pressure treated. However, it got me thinking with my this oops - do the 2x4s I added to shrink this frame technically need to be pressure treated becaude the ends are in contact with the floor?